# Bad substitution

Tags: bash, docker, debian

I have a bash script containing this line:

```
dir="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
```

This runs fine on OSX.

However, when I move it move the script on a Docker container running Debian, it fails on the above line with this message:

```
Bad substitution
```

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: What's the shebang on the script? `#!/bin/sh` isn't bash. (Even when `/bin/sh` is implemented as a symlink to bash, it runs in POSIX mode, disabling many extensions to the standard). If you want full bash syntax, your shebang *must* be `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: (Likewise, running a script with `sh yourscript` will interpret it with a shell only guaranteed to provide POSIX-baseline functionality, even if that script starts with `#!/bin/bash`).

Answer (score 1):

You are using `dash` shell, not `bash`.

Check with: `ls -la /proc/$$/exe`

Comment: `ls -la /proc/$$/exe` has the result 
`lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 16 17:20 /proc/6/exe -> /bin/bash`, so I'm not using `dash`

Comment: If using bash, then the safest thing to do would be to check if the script is called standalone, or sourced:

Comment: if [ -z "${BASH_SOURCE}" ]; then
  SCRIPTPATH=$0
else
  SCRIPTPATH=${BASH_SOURCE[0]}
fi